# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'Item_Copy' (errno: 150) unable to create table Item_Copy

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot create the table Item_Copy

```
CREATE TABLE Library
(
Library_ID int primary key,
Library_Address varchar(40),
Library_Phone bigint
);

CREATE TABLE Branch
(
Library_ID int,
Branch_Number int,
Branch_Name varchar(40),
Branch_Address varchar(40),
Branch_Phone bigint,
Branch_Hours varchar(40),
primary key (Library_ID,Branch_Number),
foreign key (Library_ID) references Library(Library_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Item_Copy
(
Item_ID int primary key,
Copy_Number int,
Copy_Condition varchar(40),
Copy_Date_Acquired date,
Copy_Cost int,
Library_ID int,
Branch_Number int,
foreign key (Library_ID) references Branch(Library_ID),
foreign key (Branch_Number) references Branch(Branch_Number),
foreign key (Item_ID) references Item(Item_ID)
);
```

Comment: Try it again with just the item_id.  If that works, drop it and add the next field.  Repeat until you find the line that caused the error.

Comment: There is no index that covers `Branch(Branch_Number)` field. The question lacks `Item` table definition as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a scientific guess (will drop if it's wrong) (is based on an assumption that `Item_ID` definitions match):

You wanted a compound foreign key, not 2 separated FKs:

```
foreign key (Library_ID, Branch_Number) references Branch(Library_ID, Branch_Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a child relation, parent column must have indexed.

In the parent table `Branch`, Key is defined as composite.

```
primary key (Library_ID,Branch_Number),
```

But, in the child table `Item_Copy`, you are trying to define reference keys independent on each column.

```
foreign key (Library_ID) references Branch(Library_ID),
foreign key (Branch_Number) references Branch(Branch_Number),
```

This is only acceptable when each of these fields are referring to respective parent keys.
But `Branch(Branch_Number)` has no key defined in `Branch` table. And hence is the error.

**Change**:

```
foreign key (Library_ID) references Branch(Library_ID),
foreign key (Branch_Number) references Branch(Branch_Number),
```

**To**:

```
foreign key (Library_ID, Branch_Number)
    references Branch(Library_ID, Branch_Number),
```